# pl sql query takes more time to execute

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, plsql

I found this PL/SQL at my workplace and I couldn't find the reason why this script takes so much time to execute:

```
DECLARE
    query           VARCHAR(500);
    ref_cur         REFCURSOR;
    product_listH   VARCHAR(1000):='';
    product_listA   VARCHAR(1000):='';  
    product_listP   VARCHAR(1000):='';  
    product     VARCHAR(100):='';
begin

    query := ' select hotelname
                 from sch1.resconfirmsv rr,
                      sch1.reshoteldetailssv hd,sch2.respkgconfirmsv r '||
               ' where rr.id = hd.resconfirmid and
                       hd.resconfirmid = r.hotelconfirmid and
                       r.id = ' || m_resconfirmid || '';
    OPEN ref_cur FOR EXECUTE query;
    LOOP
        FETCH ref_cur INTO product;
        IF NOT FOUND THEN
            EXIT; -- exit loop
        END IF;
        product_listH  := product_listH||''||trim(COALESCE(product,'-'))||',<br>';
    END LOOP;
    product_listH := rtrim(trim(product_listH),',<br>');
    CLOSE ref_cur;


    query := ' select distinct programname
                 from sch1.resconfirmsv rr,
                      sch3.resactivitysv a,
                      sch3.resprogramsv hx,
                      sch2.respkgconfirmsv r '||
               ' where rr.id = hx.resconfirmid and
                       hx.id=a.resprogramid and
                       hx.resconfirmid = r.activitiesconfirmid and
                       r.id = ' || m_resconfirmid || '';
        OPEN ref_cur FOR EXECUTE query;
        LOOP
            FETCH ref_cur INTO product;
            IF NOT FOUND THEN
                EXIT; -- exit loop
            END IF;
            product_listA  := product_listA||''||trim(COALESCE(product,'-'))||',<br>';
        END LOOP;
        product_listA := rtrim(trim(product_listA),',<br>');
        CLOSE ref_cur;
        product_listP := product_listH || ',<br>' || product_listA;
        product_listP := rtrim(trim(product_listP),',<br>');
        product_listP = ltrim(rtrim(product_listP,',<br>'),',<br>');
        RETURN product_listP;
    end;
```

without this script total run-time is 12.176 sec and with this script it takes up to 18.802 sec.means this gets at least 6 seconds to execute. All the needed columns are indexed. Anybody can tell me where the places need to be more optimize in this query?

Comment: What is `m_resconfirmid`? I don't see it's declaration anywhere.

Comment: Check you should have proper indexes on tables that you are using in your query.

Comment: @Mikhail 'm_resconfirmid' is the argument of integer type when calling the function

Comment: May be dependet on your tables. How large are they?

Comment: every table has more than 500 records

Comment: @user1727557 Ok, first thing you should try to boost this, is parametrizing your queries, not using parameters just as a plain text.

Comment: You've only got two queries. Run each individually in whatever tool you use (e.g. PL/SQL Developer, SQL*Plus, etc) and see how long they take to execute, given appropriate values for `m_resconfirmid`. The purpose of this is to figure out which query is slowing you down. Once you know that you can figure out why. Nobody here has access to your systems so there's not much we can do except the obvious things like "Make sure you've got all the indexes defined", which you've already stated you do. (BTW - I'm guessing it's the second query. What table is PROGRAMNAME on?)

Comment: thanks @BobJarvis.programname is on 'resactivitysv'.But if we consider programname why don't we consider the 'hotelname' in previous query?

Comment: Check the execution plans of the statements using `explain plan` (details in the manual)

Answer (score 0):

Why declaring the cursor as a seperate varchar?
Instead i'd use the normal declaration of a cursor, it takes time to analyze the query to be executed by Oracle, so (between the declare- and Begin-labels of your current code:

```
cursor ref_cur as
  select distinct programname
  from sch1.resconfirmsv rr,
       sch3.resactivitysv a,
       sch3.resprogramsv hx,
       sch2.respkgconfirmsv r '||
  where rr.id = hx.resconfirmid and
   hx.id=a.resprogramid and
   hx.resconfirmid = r.activitiesconfirmid and
   r.id = m_resconfirmid;
```

Now you can use

```
For x in ref_cur loop
```

The same thing for query#2.

Cheers